# Iteration logic - selective column combination

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, python-itertools

I have the below code which creates all possible combinations of columns in a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools as iter
dates = pd.date_range('20180107',periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,12),index=dates,columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKL'))
cc = list(iter.combinations(df.columns,3))
df2 = pd.concat([df[c[1]].mul(2).sub(df[c[2]]).sub(df[c[0]]) for c in cc], axis=1, keys=cc)
```

So for a df with columns A through L this returns a new dataframe with ABC, ABD, ABE, ABF... etc (2* middle column - left - right in calculation)

What I need to do is filter through the columns in df2 to remove all but the symmetric combinations of columns, i.e keeping ABC, BCD, CDE etc and ACE, BDF etc all the way through to AFK etc (i.e equal spacing between col1/col2 and col2/col3 in the col1/col2/col3 combination).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you filter the `cc` list before you even create the columns. Then you don't have to deal with filtering the MultiIndex:

```
def is_symmetrical(x, y, z):
    return ord(z) - ord(y) == ord(y) - ord(x)

cc = [c for c in cc if is_symmetrical(*c)]
```

Comment: That works, thanks. But it does fall over if A B C etc are strings, rather than single characters. e.g i get:TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 11 found Any thoughts to avoid this if A B C etc were strings, rather than single characters?

Comment: When you have strings, you indeed can't rely on `ord(x)`, which exploits the integer unicode code points of single ascii letters. You will have to write a different `is_symmetrical` function. I can't help you with that as I don't know what kind of strings you have and how their symmetry is defined. Try writing the method yourself, if you get stuck, then open a new question with some examples of your strings and your `is_symmetrical` attempt. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, rather than ABC...etc my columns are U8, Z8, H9, M9, U9, Z9, H0 , H1 M1, U1, ,Z1, H2... so 12 columns still, just 2 characters in each rather than 1

Comment: If they column names are always two characters, one letter and one number, you can rewrite `is_symmetrical` using `ord(x[0])` for the letter part and `int(x[1])` for the number part to define the new symmetric function.

Comment: Do you have an example of that new is_symmetrical function should look?

Comment: Please refer the my first comment. Define what symmetry means for these two-letter words. Only then can you (or anybody else) translate it into code. I pointed you to ways to access info on the letter and the number that you can use in the method in the last comment. Some logic functions might be of help, like `and`, `or` or `not`.